# repetir las columnas en consulta IN mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy generando una consulta con la funcion IN en mysql que repite el campo ID, pero solo muestra una vez el resultado, por ejemplo necesito:

```
ID | PRODUCTO
----------------------
1  | CARNE
1  | CARNE
2  | QUESO
2  | QUESO
3  | POLLO
4  | PAN
```

Pero en lugar a eso muestra

```
ID | PRODUCTO
----------------------
1  | CARNE
2  | QUESO
3  | POLLO
4  | PAN
```

Mi consulta seria similar a esta

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_prod IN(1,1,2,2,3,4)
```

Comment: No es comprensible que necesites filas exactamente iguales duplicadas.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de tu tabla `productos`:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  producto varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO productos (producto) VALUES
  ('CARNE'),('QUESO'),('POLLO'),('PAN');
```

Generaría una tabla `ocurrencias`:

```
CREATE TABLE ocurrencias(
  id_ocurrencia int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id int
  );
INSERT INTO ocurrencias (id) VALUES
  (1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(4);
```

Y obtendría el resultado que esperas con un simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT id,producto
  FROM ocurrencias
  JOIN productos USING(id);

+------+----------+
| id   | producto |
+------+----------+
|    1 | CARNE    |
|    1 | CARNE    |
|    2 | QUESO    |
|    2 | QUESO    |
|    3 | POLLO    |
|    4 | PAN      |
+------+----------+
```

Desconozco para qué lo utilizarás, pero ten en cuenta que, en Álgebra Relacional, no tienen sentido las tuplas duplicadas sin nada que las diferencie. Por eso no puedes obtener el resultado que esperas de forma inmediata. Es decir, que a esas repeticiones u ocurrencias, las acompañes de un `id_ocurrencia`, `fecha_pedido` o lo que corresponda...